# Python/Django - cannot import my own models.py

Tags: python, django, import

This is ridiculous. My folders:

```
eVistA
--manage.py
--evista
----__init__.py
----settings.py
----urls.py
----wsgi.py
--fms
----__init__.py
----models.py
----tests.py
----views.py
----features
------__init__.py
------funding.feature
------funding.py
```

In funding.py I have

```
from fms.models import *
```

When I run lettuce I get:

```
ImportError: No module named fms.models
```

Gonna have to shoot myself.

---

Just for laughs I put a copy of models.py in the features folder and now

```
from models import *
```

results in

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SE
TTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

In manage.py I have

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "evista.settings")
```

Comment: Can you simply do `import fms`?

Comment: Tried that: No module named fms. Which is actually true since fms is a package.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be in business with:

```
from fms.models import *
```

Seems you don't run lettuce with Django, you have to run:

```
python manage.py harvest
```

From the top folder that contains `manage.py` of course.

Comment: If this is the answer, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left. And you posted a few non-answers here, so just a reminder: Stack Overflow isn’t a forum, and the answers section is for answers only. Comment, edit, or just don’t post instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
from evista.fms.models import *
```

Comment: No module named evista.fms.models. It's pretty determined not to see anything outside its own directory. Also, import fms.models gets "No module named fms.models".